# Windows 8.1 KB2919355 Update Fails endlessly

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

A client of mine has a almost netbook deathly slow laptop running Windows8.1 and of all the updates to fail the 600~800 megabyte KB2919355-x64 was the one to refuse to work.

I followed the directions on the following website however the update still failed...

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-1-update-fails-to-install

I can't charge the little old lady in to oblivion for my time... It *really* doesn't help that Microsoft refuses to give security updates if you don't have this update (apparently)...so how do we give this problem a high five in the face with a chair?

Here are the [CBS log](http://www.mediafire.com/download/696up4oebwsq5w3/j_cbs_logs.7z) files.

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\logs\CBS** to the desktop, zip it and upload the zip to a cloud service and post the link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Got the files, zipped them up and uploaded them to MediaFire.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Setup of the update fails becasue you have deleted/moved the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools`:

```
2014-09-29 10:31:37, Error                 CSI    00000d04 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #11385747# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = (AllowSharingViolation), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES), oa = @0x5b315bd808->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[77]"\??\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0x5b315bd7e8, as = (null), fa = 0, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd = FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-09-29 10:31:37, Error                 CSI    00000d05@2014/9/29:14:31:37.614 (F) base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(2155): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
```

Create an empty folder `Administrative Tools` under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` and the setup should work now. If not, share the new logs.

Comment: Lame; it's a client's computer that I'll be at Saturday late afternoon/evening so I'll respond when I get back. Thanks!